# What kind of RAM module will work with my computer and how to place it?

Tags: memory, upgrade

I recently bought a Dell Vostro V3460 with the processor 3rd Gen Intel® Core™ i5-3210M Processor (2.50GHz, with Turbo Boost 2.0 up to 3.10GHz).

It only has 4GB Shared Single Channel DDR3 Memory. I need more than that, so I plan to purchase a replacement 8GB RAM module.

So, my two questions are:

- How do I find a RAM module that will work with my computer?
- How do I perform the upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do need to buy a certain type of RAM.  To be exact you need ***PC3-10600/12800 DDR3 204-Pin SODIMM memory***.  [**Memory Stock**](http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellVostro3460.html) actually does a good job of telling you what the specs are on any computer and also recommends upgrades.

As long as you buy and install the correct type of RAM you should not experience any issue.  First thing I would do is remove the memory you have currently and see what it is.  It will be either PC3-10600 or PC3-12800.  If there is only one stick of 4GB then you need only buy one stick of 4GB of the same type either PC3-10600 or PC3-12800.

Comment: Do you suggest any specific company?

Comment: I buy a lot of my computer stuff from TigerDirect or Newegg.  Just navigate to the memory stick you want and then sort by customer rating then chose a memory stick that is highly rated and at an acceptable price range.  That way you will have a lesser chance of getting a bad stick.

Comment: @Krishna Questions about where to buy something are [not really a good fit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa) here.